# How to prevent re-render caused because of calling hook useSelector()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

`EDIT` It caused by `<React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode>` in `index.js`. I am not sure why but it is odd.

I noticed hook `useSelector()` caused the app re-render needlessly. Is this expected? If yes, should I drop using `redux-toolkit-js`?

I haven't tested this behavior on React Native but I think re-rendering in React Native will become an issue.

Hook `useSelector` caused the app to re-render 2 times more and it compounds, meaning If the app without `Redux` will re-render only 2 times, caused by a state update, simply calling `useSelector()` will cause the app to re-render 4 times.

This is the steps I took to reproduce the problem:

1. npx create-react-app my-app --template redux
2. cd my-app
3. npm start
4. add console.log in `App.js` and `features/counter/Counter.js`

```
let i = 0;

function App() {
  i++
  console.log("App()", i)
  
  ...
}
```

5. Check your browser DevTools's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React does an extra render in development environments in strict mode to help you find bugs and do some checks for you. It doesn't do this in a production build.

From the docs for [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`